# Why does symlink to VLC break but .bash_profile alias works?

Tags: bash, vlc-media-player, symbolic-link, .bash-profile

## problem

I can execute VLC from the command line using a `.bash_profile` alias but not using a sym link.

VLC is located at `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC` on my machine

---

## sym link

I tried two different sym links from my user's `bin`:

- `ln -s /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC vlc`
- `ln -s ../../../Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC vlc`

For both, the terminal simply outputs the VLC version and exits:

```
️ ☞☞☞ vlc Peter\ Tosh\ -\ Stepping\ Razor-aLJFRgE4Ywk.mp3
VLC media player 3.0.3 Vetinari (revision 3.0.3-1-0-gc2bb759264)
️ ☞☞☞
```

---

## alias

When I made an alias for VLC in my `.bash_profile`:

```
alias vlc="/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC"
```

things worked fine

```
️ ☞☞☞ vlc Peter\ Tosh\ -\ Stepping\ Razor-aLJFRgE4Ywk.mp3
VLC media player 3.0.3 Vetinari (revision 3.0.3-1-0-gc2bb759264)
[00007fe25051eaa0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
```

I can just continue to use the alias, but I'd like to understand *why* the sym links didn't work.

This answer discusses [differences between symbolic links and aliases](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/2994) but doesn't seem to resolve my particular problem.

Comment: Does symlink named `VLC` (uppercase) works?

Comment: I see no reason for this, unless there is another `vlc` already in existence. Enter `type -a vlc` to see if there is (for instance) a function with this name or a script higher in the `PATH` list, which would supersede the link.